# Help Understanding Network Output

Tags: networking, lubuntu, ethernet

I am in need to find my `wlan0` device.  I have tried running `ifconfig` & `nmcli` & `lspci` but `wlan0` is not output from any of those commands.  I understand that this just means that my network interface is different, but how do I determine which is my network interface?

This is my ifconfig output:

```
ur@Backup:~$ ifconfig
ens1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:08:46:14:78
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:36047 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36047 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:27773272 (27.7 MB)  TX bytes:27773272 (27.7 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00 
          inet addr:10.184.1.6  P-t-P:10.184.1.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3420989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3468649 errors:0 dropped:71 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:3877869781 (3.8 GB)  TX bytes:418891400 (418.8 MB)

wlp16s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:de:bd:48:02 
          inet addr:192.168.5.20  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:deff:febd:4802/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7008389 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5770457 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4494858291 (4.4 GB)  TX bytes:3906493268 (3.9 GB)
```

Comment: Try `ifconfig -a`

Comment: @heemayl - same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming convention changed, see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

> Starting with v197 systemd/udev will automatically assign predictable,
>   stable network interface names for all local Ethernet, WLAN and WWAN
>   interfaces. This is a departure from the traditional interface naming
>   scheme ("eth0", "eth1", "wlan0", ...), but should fix real problems.

and https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L20

> - Two character prefixes based on the type of interface:
>
>   - en -- Ethernet
>   - sl -- serial line IP (slip)
>   - wl -- wlan
>   - ww -- wwan

See the link for types of names, in your case (some of the code was edited)

> P (domain) p(bus)s(slot)PCI geographical location

so wlan0 became wlp16s0

wl == wlan

p16 == bus 16

s0 == slot 0

Comment: Thank you for that information.  What is the difference between the wl and ww?

Comment: WLAN is intended for “local” use (the “L” in WLAN). AKA Wi-Fi . WWAN is a mobile broadband option(cell phones) that covers a “wide” area (the “W” in WWAN). AKA “3G” or a “4G” network.